Pick $k$ numbered marbles placed around a circle such that at least $a_i$ marbles not picked between marbles $m_{j_i}$ and $m_{j_{i+1}}$
This is problem 9.86 from A path to combinatorics for undergraduates.
Let $k$ and $n$ be positive integers, and let $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ be positive integers. Marbles $m_1,m_2,...,m_n$ are placed around a circle in clockwise order. Zachary is asked to pick $k$ marbles $m_{j_1},m_{j_2},...,m_{j_k}$, with $j_1\lt j_2\lt \cdots \lt j_k$, such that there are at least $a_i$ marbles that are not picked between $m_{j_i}$ and $m_{j_{i+1}}$ in the clockwise direction. (Here marble $m_{n+k}$ is the same as marble $m_k$.) In how many ways can Zachary complete his task?
Here is my attempt:
Let $x_i$ be the number of marbles not picked between $m_{j_i}$ and $m_{j_{i+1}}$ in the clockwise direction. Then we have
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_k=n-k$$
with the constraints that $x_i\ge a_i$.
By Stars and Bars, the number of nonnegative integral $k$-tuples $(x_1,x_2,...,x_k)$ satisfying the above is $\binom{n-k-\sum_{i=1}^ka_k+k-1}{k-1}$.
The problem that I run into is that different $k$-tuples in general don't generate the same number of choices for the marbles $m_{j_1},m_{j_2},...,m_{j_k}$.
For example, take $k=2,n\ge5, a_1=a_2=1$. In this case, $(x_1,x_2)=(1,n-3)$ works. This generate $n-2$ choices for the marbles, namely $(m_1,m_3),(m_2,m_4)...,(m_{n-2},m_n)$. Now, $(x_1,x_2)=(2,n-4)$ also works and generates $n-3$ choices for the marbles, namely $(m_1,m_4),(m_2,m_5)...,(m_{n-3},m_n)$.
How can this problem be tackled?

In you example, you say that $(1,n-3)$ generates $n-2$ tuples choices, but I think it actually $n$ choices, since you missed $(m_{n-1,}m_{1})$ and $(m_{n},m_{2})$. Similarly, $(2,n-4)$ generates $n$ choices. Do you agree, or did I misunderstand the problem?

We need $j_1\lt j_2\lt \cdots \lt j_k$.

The $a_i$ unpicked marbles need to be between $m_{j_i}$ and $m_{j_{i+1}}$ in the clockwise direction.

You are right. It seems I have misintepreted the problem.

Following up on that, the answer to the problem would be $\binom{n-1-\sum_{i=1}^ka_i}{k-1}$ times $\binom{n}{1}$ (for choosing marble $m_{j_i}$) divided by $k$ (to eliminate the repeated cases), i.e.,
$$\binom{n-1-\sum_{i=1}^ka_i}{k-1}\frac{n}{k}$$
EDIT:
Suppose you choose marble $m_1$ as $m_{j_1}$. Now, $x_i$ is the number of marbles not picked between $m_{j_i}$ and $m_{j_{i+1}}$ and $\binom{n-1-\sum_{i=1}^ka_i}{k-1}$ is the number of ways you can choose the remaining $(k-1)$ marbles such that there are at least $a_i$ marbles that are not picked between $m_{j_i}$ and $m_{j_{i+1}}$. But, instead of $m_1$, you could have picked any of the marbles as $m_{j_1}$. Furthermore, for any selection {$m_{j_1},m_{j_2},...,m_{j_k}$}, there are k possible permutations:  {$m_{j_2},m_{j_3},...,m_{j_k},m_{j_1}$}, {$m_{j_3},m_{j_4},...,m_{j_k},m_{j_1},m_{j_2}$} and so on. Thus, giving the final result as $\binom{n-1-\sum_{i=1}^ka_i}{k-1}$ times $\frac{n}{k}$.

Could you please explain further? What does choosing marble $m_{j_i}$ do? And why is each repeated case counted $k$ times?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I have edited my answer.

Not every permutation (or even selection) works. Note that we need $j_1\lt j_2\lt \cdots \lt j_k$.

I believe $j_1\lt j_2\lt \cdots \lt j_k$ only means that we are to choose the marbles in a clockwise fashion.

You can also see that the ($k=2$, $a_1=a_2=1$) case essentially gives the number of diagonals in an n sided polygon.

I suspect that this problem is not worded in the way the author intended. However, I will solve the problem as written.
The constraint $j_1<j_2<\dots<j_k$ forces us to think linearly.
If we think of the marbles as being linearly arranged from $m_1$ to $m_n$, then removing the $k$ selected marbles divides the line into $k+1$ consecutive blocks. Let $y_0,y_1,\dots,y_k$ denote the length of these gaps. For each $i\in \{1,\dots,k-1\}$, $y_i$ is the number of marbles between $m_{j_i}$ and $m_{j_{i+1}}$. Then, $y_0$ is the number of marbles to the left of $m_{j_1}$, and $y_k$ is the number of marbles to the right of $m_{j_k}$. The constraints are
$$
\begin{align}
y_0+y_1+\dots+y_k&=n-k
\\
y_i&\ge a_i & (1\le i\le k-1)
\\
y_0+y_k&\ge a_k
\end{align}$$
The constraint $y_0+y_k\ge a_k$ introduces the most difficulty. The only thing I can think to do is to look at each possible value of $y_0+y_k$, using stars-and-bars to count the number of ways to assign $y_1,\dots,y_{k-1}$ for each choice, and then writing the final answer as a sum.
If $y_0+y_k=s$, for some $s$ such that $a_k\le s\le n-k$, then we must count solutions to
$$
\begin{align}
y_1+\dots+y_{k-1}&=n-k-y_0-y_k
\\
&=n-k-s
\\
y_i&\ge a_i & (1\le i\le k-1)
\end{align}$$
By stars-and-bars, the number of solutions is $$\binom{n-k-s-(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i)+k-2}{k-2}$$
Furthermore, for each choice of $s$, we must choose the values $(y_0,y_k)$ such that $y_0+y_k=s$. There are $s+1$ ways to do this; the list of ways is $(s,0),(s-1,1),\dots,(0,s)$.
Summing over all possible choices of $s$, you get a final answer of
$$
\sum_{s=a_k}^{n-k}(s+1)\cdot \binom{n-k-s-(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i)+k-2}{k-2}.
$$
Be forewarned, I am using the convention that $\binom nk=0$ if $n<k$, inlucding when $n$ is negative, which allows me to be sloppy with the upper index of the summation. If $s$ is too large, then the extra summands are zero, by this convention.
